# Difference between ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED and ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the difference between

- ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
- ACTION_SCREEN_ON

  in android? and Which is actually used to handle sleep mode of device?

Comment: You really do not see any difference between completing booting and switching screen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

ACTION_SCREEN_ON: Broadcast Action: Sent when the device wakes up and becomes interactive. **Each time!**
For historical reasons, the name of this broadcast action refers to the power state of the screen but it is actually sent in response to changes in the overall interactive state of the device. I guess this is one is used for handling sleep mode.

ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED: Broadcast Action: This is broadcast **once**, after the system has finished booting. It can be used to perform application-specific initialization, such as installing alarms. You must hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is sent when device boots up and boot sequence is finished. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

ACTION_SCREEN_ON
Sent when the device wakes up and becomes interactive.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON